# ASP.Net4.0 web application Eventlogging Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application Event logs show:

> *Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted*.

Pasted below is the line of code I use to write to `EventLog`:

```
Logging.LogWriter.WriteEventLog(Logging.WindowsEvent.ERROR_XXXX_XXXX, 
                               "Testing ERROR_XXXX_XXXX.", TrackingGuid);
```

Pasted below is what I see in the EventViewer -->Application Evet log  -->"General" Tab

> The description for Event ID xxxx from source Application Error cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> 2011-10-27 16:27:51.841: TrackingGuid: 1111a70-4618-4ce8-8x5c-9x69e26519c0: Testing ERROR_XXXX_XXXX.
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

I am using: Windows 7, IIS 7.5, VS2010 Ultimate, Framework 4.0

Any Idea  why this error is? Please note that the above message says:

> *Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted*.

I don't understand which component is missing / corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk2a9kek.aspx) - in the Remarks section, it mentions that, "You must create and configure the event source before writing the first entry with the source."

Windows cannot find the ERROR_XXXXX_XXXX in the Windows Event Log, so it displays the error "the message is not found in the string/message table".  You could add your message to the Windows Event log or create your own [event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller.aspx).